# How to configure a Web Server that can display data from my Raspberry PI?

Tags: raspbian, networking, web-server, database

I would like to know how to configure a web server that can display data.

The data would come from the Raspberry Pi and Windows Azure.

Comment: How is the data stored on your RPi or Windows Azure? All of the major programming languages used for web development (Python, Ruby, PHP) have database interfaces  which will work for making remote connections to your database server.

Comment: I think the real question here is how to host a web server, that he wants to access Azure may be useful information in choosing software stack for any specialized libraries there may be. For example, you could write a service (program) using Mono, C# and AspNetWebStack to serve dynamic data from Azure via your Pi, since there are specialized APIs in .NET for connecting to Azure. Azure services aren't necessarily represented by a database, for example their 'Storage' product, and you will find many RESTful APIs you can use regardless of programming language.

Comment: Using RPi, sensor to detect and RPi get the data from sensor and next, send it to Windows Azure's Sqldatabase. Final stage, will be using a web server to display the data from Windows Azure's Sqldatabase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand you want something like FTP.

If you want to have access to data from outside of the local network, ability to upload and download, you will need these:

1. Install and set some web server, like nginx (or Apache, but I nginx was easier for me to set).
2. Install and set some ftp service, like svftp.

If you just need to "display" them (~download them), then web server is enough. 
https://github.com/Farence/tutos
You haven't written what distro are you using, so it's hard to give you better advice for installing and setting it.

I've written a little guide for my friends on github [here (RPi.md)](https://github.com/Farence/tutos) - it's also with some details about how IP addresses and domains works etc. and I added configs.

Here are some other usefull informations:
http://www.instructables.com/id/Raspberry-Pi-Web-Server/step9/Install-an-FTP-server/

http://mounirmesselmeni.github.io/2013/12/03/install-vsftpd-on-linux-and-configure-nginx-as-webserver/

or similiar. Google is your friend (keywords: ftp, webserver, nginx, file web share, home server...)

Comment: Hello and welcome to RPi SE! Thank you for your answer. Usually, it is encouraged to not only provide a few links (which are quite good, by the way), but also describe what the steps taken in the link would be. You never know if a website will be taken down tomorrow. Feel free to edit your answer to improve it!

Comment: Sorry for that. I'm going to improve it. :) Thanks for info.

Comment: Thanks for the details, user2319172. I will give it a try.

Comment: I added some tutorials I've written for my friends [here (RPi.md)](https://github.com/Farence/tutos) with configs.